# wierd s charachter in php artisan output

Tags: php, laravel

i have an strange problem : i am using laravel 8 and jetstream and when i try to change profile photo in jetstream i get this error :

```
index.js:50 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at index.js:50
```

and when i run any command like `php artisan config:clear` and first of output i get a `s` charachter like below :

```
sConfiguration cache cleared!
```

i guessed i should miss writed this some where i search all the places but no luck with that .

Comment: you have a random `s` some where ... what else do you want us to do about it?

Comment: i wanted to know if its a common problem with jetstream because i used that